# how to load a script code in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor and I want to load some codes.

for example:

```
<div id="15175860223750456"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/xom4D?data[rnddiv]=15175860223750456&data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>
```

how can I load this script between my content?

Answer (score 0):

It's just not possible. CKEditor strips or encodes all `script` elements as they're the easiest mean to perform XSS attacks.

However if you want to embed some media, CKEditor 4 [has dedicated plugin for it](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mediaembed.html).